# How to change cursor size on raspberry Pi Debian?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, mouse-cursor

I am new to Linux and trying to make the cursor for my Raspberry Pi larger and am using raspbian. I downloaded "larger mouse cursors for X" but cannot figure out how to open it. Is this even the right software for doing this? Or is there an easier way to make the cursor size larger?

Comment: [How do I change the cursor and its size?](//askubuntu.com/q/126491)

Comment: I followed the first suggestion and installed "dconf-editor", and changed the "cursor size" to 48 and then rebooted but nothing happens. I wonder if maybe something is overriding it? Because it still says that the value is 48 in "dconf-editor"